# making scrolling faster with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js for a website of mine. With that I can use the down button of my keyboard to scroll down, however, when I press it continuously it doesn't work, I have to give it sometime and then hit the button to further scroll down. Can anyone please let me know if the file has some sort of setting in which I can adjust the timing after which I can scroll again?

Thank you.

Here are the files for the JS. 
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

An example of how it looks:

http://benoit.jean-charles.perso.sfr.fr/telechargement/DiversProg/Sitenonbasetestinfos/examples/easing.html#secondPage

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is suppose to work that way **to avoid problems with other devices** such as Mac laptops using trackpads, Apple magic mouse or even some touch devices.

But if you really want to take the risk, you could do it by changing the variable `scrollDelay`:

```
//Defines the delay to take place before being able to scroll to the next section
//BE CAREFUL! Not recommened to change it under 400 for a good behavior in laptops and
//Apple devices (laptops, mouses...)
var scrollDelay = 600;
```

You can find it [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js#L64).